# If an ant sized intelligent creature was swallowed alive by a human, would the death be painful?

Tags: biology

So, I’m an astronaut. I got stranded on this planet, and I found a civilization of ant sized, intelligent beings that thought I was a god! They did whatever I said, no matter the ridiculousness of the request, yet they face my divine retribution.

I ordered them to create a large farm of fruit, as my first request. Than I ordered them to harvest the fruit, and than ferment it, and finally build a to giant cup. What can I say, I love myself some brew.

Anyway, a lot of slaves lives were lost building and farming. The tiny king’s son was overseeing a group of slaves building my cup. I wanted a taste test, so I drunk a small sip of the alcohol. The kings son and the slaves, accidentally got caught in the backwash, and I swallowed him, whole.

I’ve been pretty depressed about that. From the struggling I felt in my throat, he didn’t want to be there. My question is, will he die quickly, or will his death come slowly and painfully?

Comment: Did you chew/mouthwash before swallowing?

Comment: @L.Dutch: Nope, just chugged the hole thing down

Comment: Imagine being slowly run over by a dump truck while it's going through a car wash... now add thousands of gallons of saliva...  not pretty.

Comment: @Joe: Is it painful?

Comment: I'd assume he'd asphyxiate in your stomach while acids sting his skin, but I don't have the stomach right now to look up what gases and acids are in a standard gut.

Comment: Are the beings ant-sized, or intelligent ants?  Pain isn't a function of intelligence (otherwise my cat wouldn't feel pain), it's a function of the complexity of the nervous system.  I don't feel pain when I cut my finger nails, there's no nerves to indicate a problem - and I like to think that I'm at least somewhat intelligent (*citation required*).  In other words, if you claim your creatures feel pain, then they do.  If you claim they do not, then they don't.

Comment: @JBH: Ant sized intelligent beings, with complex nervous systems.

Comment: [Pain... Lots of pain...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6e5E20k9jY)  (Oh, and please edit your question with the answers to comment queries.  Thanks!)

Comment: How strong a drink? Does he know how to hold his breath? The alcohol is the only hope for a quick end, and some ants are quite amazing at keeping out liquids when submersed.

Comment: @Not store bought dirt: As strong as your average glass of whiskey

Comment: @Giter Stomach fluid is essentially 30% HCl plus water and enzymes. From my first summer job washing laboratory glassware, I can tell you emphatically that 30% HCl burns painfully (but not instantly and it is easily neutralized with soap).

Comment: @RobertPaul What kind of outer covering do they have?  Skin?  Chitinous carapace? Boney carapace? Gold leaf?

Comment: @Pojo-guy: An exoskeleton, like a crab, or lobsters, only softer

Comment: @RobertPaul That's a chitinous carapace.  its hardness is determined by its thickness and shape. Chitin is almost impervious to human digestive enzymes, unlike bone which is subject to degradation by acids (think of dental cavities).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go along with His Royal Highness from your mouth down your stomach.

First he will be in your mouth: saliva and the liquid, being liquid, will have a certain surface tension, which for an ant size creature is a terrible force. When earth ants drink, they have to take a firm grip on something to avoid being sucked in by the water.

[image: drinking ant]

So, being surrounded by the mixture of saliva and drink will not be pleasurable, for sure. Fear and despair will skyrocket.

Then you swallow, and with the water His Royal Highness will slide down your esophagus until your stomach. If you recently had some food, he will splash into a solution of hydrochloric acid (HCl), which will painfully kill him. This will spare him the trip along your bowels to get out and see the sunlight on the other side of the world.

If you didn't had food recently, he will struggle some more, trying to escape the liquid mass, which is slowly getting more and more acid. Again, painful death plus fear and despair.

Next time if you can't spit, be sure to chew thoroughly. At least it will be fast.

Comment: Oh my God. Are you saying all the ants I swallowed in real life suffered that much

Comment: Also, wouldn’t getting shredded apart by my teeth also hurt his majesty

Comment: @Separatrix: Ok than, wouldnt his royal highnesses also suffer from getting shredded apart from my teeth

Comment: @RobertPaul things with central nervous systems stop reporting pain when it is smooshed and apparently shock often keeps sudden loss of limb level injuries from being noticed as pain.

Comment: But still, wouldn’t getting grinded alive while totally conscious by agonizing

Comment: Wouldn’t getting grinded up by my teeth still be painful

Comment: @RobertPaul, head crushed, pain gone.

Comment: @Separatrix, fixed

Comment: @L. Dutch: Funny story, I used to swallow ants whole as a kid, without chewing. Real ants can’t feel much suffering, right?

Comment: @RobertPaul I should be an ant to know. However, having saved ants and wasps from drowning, I can tell you they need time to recover.

Comment: @L.Dutch: Hey I don’t assume species on the internet. I thought you might be an ant, who somehow knows how to write

Comment: @RobertPaul On the internet, no one knows you're an ant

Answer (score 0):

If the organism's size approximates that of an ant, and was swallowed whole, and he was able to hold his breath, then its life expectancy would be about 7 minutes. Due to its chitinous shell, which is essentially impervious to the human digestive system, he would remain unharmed so long as he was able to hold his breath.

After 7 minutes he would need to breathe and, unless he was heroically climbing the trachea, he would probably inhale stomach fluids which are roughly 30% hydrochloric acid. Unlike the outer shell, the tracheal tubes and or other breathing apparatus are not impervious. At this time he would die a painful death, comparable to death by chlorine gas.